# how to delete warnings in reactive inputs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could anyone can tell me why I get an error when I change a dataset in first `selectInput` widget? When I change a dataset from `diamonds` to `mtcars` I get an error `Could not find 'carat'` in `input$bins` and in the plot just for one second and after that everything works fine. Why it happened?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)
data(mtcars)


ui <- fluidPage(
      column(3,
             selectInput("data", "", choices = c('mtcars', 'diamonds')),
             uiOutput('server_cols'),
             uiOutput('server_bins')
             ),
      column(9,
             plotOutput("plot")
             )


)

server <- function(input, output) {

      data <- reactive({
            switch(input$data,
                   diamonds = diamonds,
                   mtcars = mtcars)
      })

      output$server_cols <- renderUI({
            data <- data()
            nam <- colnames(data)
            selectInput('cols', "Choose numeric columns:", choices = nam[sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x))])
      })

      output$server_bins <- renderUI({
            if (!is.null(input$cols)) {
                  df <- data()
                  x <- eval(input$cols)
                  max_value <- max(df[,x])

                  sliderInput('bins','Choose number of bins:', min = 0.1, 
                              max = max_value, 
                              value = max_value/2) 
            }
      })

      output$plot <- renderPlot({
            if (!is.null(input$cols) & !is.null(input$bins)) {
                  basicData <- data()
                  var <- eval(input$cols)

                  ggplot(basicData, aes_string(var)) +
                              geom_histogram(binwidth = input$bins, color = 'white', fill = 'red')
            }    

      })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Because `carat` is a column name in `diamonds` dataset. You can have a look at the `mtcars` dataset, and choose a column name from there.

Comment: I understand what happened. But I do not know how to avoid this warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your respective output objects respond to any changes of your input variables. Thus, when you change your dataset via `input$data`, the plot rebuilds itself, although `input$cols` did not yet adjust. Actually, try inserting some `print("a")` inside the `output$plot` to see that it is called up to three times if you change `input$data`.

The fix is to rethink your reaction logic and let your elements respond only to specific changes, to get some kind of response "thread".

For example, `input$data` should only trigger `output$server_cols`. And `output$server_bins` should only be triggered by `input$cols` (because this already implies that `input$data` changed earlier). Ultimately, `output$plot` just has to listen to changes of `input$bins` (because changes in `input$cols` and `input$data` always result in changes of `input$bins` since it is at the end of the thread).

Here is my suggestion using `isolate`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)
data(mtcars)


ui <- fluidPage(
  column(3,
    selectInput("data", "", choices = c('mtcars', 'diamonds')),
    uiOutput('server_cols'),
    uiOutput('server_bins')
   ),
   column(9,
     plotOutput("plot")
   )    
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    switch(input$data, diamonds = diamonds, mtcars = mtcars)
  })

  output$server_cols <- renderUI({
    data <- data()
    nam <- colnames(data)
    selectInput('cols', "Choose numeric columns:", choices = nam[sapply(data, function(x) is.numeric(x))])
  })

  output$server_bins <- renderUI({
    if (!is.null(input$cols)) {
      df <- isolate(data())
      x <- eval(input$cols)
      max_value <- max(df[,x])

      sliderInput('bins','Choose number of bins:', min = 0.1, max = max_value, value = max_value/2) 
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (!is.null(isolate(input$cols)) & !is.null(input$bins)) {
      basicData <- isolate(data())
      var <- eval(isolate(input$cols))

      ggplot(basicData, aes_string(var)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = input$bins, color = 'white', fill = 'red')
    }    
  })    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You might also want to look into `updateSelectInput` and `updateSliderInput` if you want to alter Input Elements depending on other input.

Comment: Thanks! I tried with `isolate` but actually your post clarified the mechanism of this function. Thanks!